# Docker Swarm: will restarting a single node manager delete all my services?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a single node Docker Swarm setup with a dozen services created by simply calling `docker service create [...]`.

Can anyone tell me what will happen to my services if I reboot my node? WIll they automatically restart or will I have to recreate them all?

I undestand that Swarm services and docker-compose setups are different, but in the case of having to recreate the services upon reboot, is there a way to save a docker-compose.yml file for each of my services (i.e. something that parses the output of `docker service inspect`)? Is there a better way of "saving" my services configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to recreate the services,it will remains same even after the node restart. I have tested the same in my swarm cluster. i have three node swarm setup (1 manager & 2 worker). completely stopped the worker nodes and services on worker node moved to the active node(manager node). I have restarted the active node(manager) and still i can see the services are up and running on the manager node.

before restart:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqejI.jpg)

After Restart:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OELxv.jpg)

So Even if you are running one node swarm,no need to worry about the services, it will automatically recreated automatically. Attached the screen shots for your reference.